# Pagination code issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, pagination

I have written below lines of code for acconmplishing pagination in asp.net using repeater control as

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="pagenexte_Click"
    data-rel="tooltip" data-original-title="previous page.">&laquo;</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" OnItemDataBound="rptPager_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick="Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="pagenext_Click" 
       data-rel="tooltip" data-original-title="next page.">&raquo;
</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="imgnext_Click"
    data-rel="tooltip" data-original-title="next page." Visible="false">    &raquo;
</asp:LinkButton>
```

in cs file as

```
    public void UpdatePageLables(int aPageCount)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["pages"] = null;
    }
    PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)aPageCount / PageSize);
    int recordCount = PageCount;
    if (PageSizeChanged != null)
    {
        HiddenField hd = new HiddenField();

        int current;
        current = PageIndex;
        int pre;
        int Next;
        double dblPageCount = (double)((decimal)recordCount / decimal.Parse(lstPageSize.SelectedValue));
        int pageCount = PageCount;

        List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
        if (pageCount > 0)
        {
            // pages.Add(new ListItem("First", "1", PageIndex > 1));
            current = PageIndex;
            pre = --PageIndex;
            PageIndex = current;

            // pages.Add(new ListItem("Previous", pre.ToString(), PageIndex > 1));

            for (int i = 1; i <= aPageCount; i++)
            {
                if (i <= 5)
                {
                    pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                }
            }


            int currentPage = PageIndex;
            Next = ++PageIndex;
            PageIndex = currentPage;
            //pages.Add(new ListItem("Next", Next.ToString(), PageIndex < pageCount));
            // pages.Add(new ListItem("Last", pageCount.ToString(), PageIndex < pageCount));

            hd.Value = (pre.ToString());


        }
        if (Session["pages"] != null)
        {
            rptPager.DataSource = Session["pages"];
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }

        Session["lastnumber"] = 5;
        Session["pagecount"] = aPageCount;
        Session["orignalpages"] = pages;

    }

}
protected void pagenext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
    int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
    int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
    if (lastnumber > pagecount)
    {
        Session["lastnumber"] = 1;
        lastnumber = 1;
        Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
        Session["orignalpages"] = pages;

    }


    int limit = lastnumber + 5;
    for (int i = lastnumber; i <= pagecount; i++)
    {
        if (i <= limit)
        {
            pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
        }
        else
        {
            rptPager.DataSource = Session["orignalpages"];
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }
    }


    Session["lastnumber"] = limit;
    Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;

    Session["pages"] = pages;

    rptPager.DataSource = pages;
    rptPager.DataBind();

}

protected void pagenexte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
    int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
    int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
    if (lastnumber > pagecount)
    {
        Session["lastnumber"] = pagecount - 5;
        lastnumber = pagecount - 5;
        Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
        Session["orignalpages"] = pages;

    }
    else
    {

        Session["lastnumber"] = 1;
        lastnumber = 1;
        Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
        Session["orignalpages"] = pages;
    }

    int limit = lastnumber + 5;
    for (int i = lastnumber; i <= pagecount; i++)
    {
        if (i <= limit && i>0) 
        {
            pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
        }
        else
        {
            //rptPager.DataSource = Session["orignalpages"];
            //rptPager.DataBind();
        }
    }


    Session["lastnumber"] = limit;
    Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;

    Session["pages"] = pages;

    rptPager.DataSource = pages;
    rptPager.DataBind();

}
```

Its working fine but does not display page numbers as required.
Basically I want that it should display like "1 2 3 4 5 " then clicking on next button, it should display "6 7 8 9 10" then again clicking on next button "11 12 13 14 15".... so on. The below code is generating page numbers as 
"1 2 3 4 5" clicking on next button "5 6 7 8 9 10" and then 10 11 12 13 14 15 and so on... Please help me !!! Also help me to improve code for previous button 
also...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "DataTable" javascript functionality for this problem. Please refer https://www.datatables.net/.

In this you just need to give your table Id in below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```